# How to prove the following norms equal?

Tags: polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $p_k$ be degree $k$ polynomial and $p_k = 1-\lambda q_{k-1}$ where $q_{k-1}$ is a $k-1$ degree polynomial. $C[a,b]$ be set of continuous functions equipped with sup norm. Then for $w(\lambda) = \lambda$, how to prove that $$\|p_k\|_{C[a,b]} = \left\|w\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}- q_{k-1}\right)\right\|_{C[a,b]} $$ where $w>0$ is a weight function? I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ the indeterminate of the polynomial? And what exactly is $w$? What is the domain and codomain of it? The expression $w(1/\lambda-q_{k-1})$ suggests that the domain is $C[a,b]$ and the codomain should be $C[a,b]$ as well, since you want to compute its $C[a,b]$ norm. Why do you call it a "weight function" then? Shouldn't the codomain be $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: Yes $\lambda$ is indeterminate. It is written in the  book. I am so much confused with this expression.